# Plot bar chart with errorbars from multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, errorbar

I am trying to do something that should be so simple but cannot find an answer via other's similar questions. I want to plot a bar graph of several groups of data that are stored in a dataframe with errorbar values that are also stored in the dataframe.

I have a dataframe that is coming from commercial software that has multiple columns I'd like to make into a clustered bar graph which I have only managed to do properly using df.plot.bar(). The issue I'm having now is just that I cannot figure out how to add error bars correctly from the same dataframe.

This code works fine to generate the type of plot I want from sample data in the same format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

#the groups can vary 
grp1 = 'a'
grp2 = 'b'
grp3 = 'c'

df['label'] = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']
df[grp1+'_int'] = [5,5.5,6]
df[grp1+'_SD'] = [1,2,3]
df[grp2+'_int'] = [7,6,5]
df[grp2+'_SD'] = [2,1,1.5]
df[grp3+'_int'] = [6.5,5,5.5]
df[grp3+'_SD'] = [1.5,1.5,2]

ax = df.plot.bar(x='label', y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'])
plt.show()
```

How can I add errorbars (positive only is fine, but really any errorbars) from the corresponding *_SD columns?

Edit: the issue seems to be related to the number of rows in my real dataframe. Here is an example of a working and non-working test code:

Not Working (throws ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]):

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

#the groups can vary 
grp1 = 'a'
grp2 = 'b'
grp3 = 'c'

df['label'] = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3','ID_4']
df[grp1+'_int'] = np.linspace(1,10,4)
df[grp1+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1,2,4)
df[grp2+'_int'] = np.linspace(2,8,4)
df[grp2+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1.5,3,4)
df[grp3+'_int'] = np.linspace(0.5,9,4)
df[grp3+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1,8,4)
print(df)
ax = df.plot.bar(x='label', y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'], yerr=df[[grp1+'_SD', grp2+'_SD', grp3+'_SD']].values)
plt.show()
```

Working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

#the groups can vary 
grp1 = 'a'
grp2 = 'b'
grp3 = 'c'

df['label'] = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']
df[grp1+'_int'] = np.linspace(1,10,3)
df[grp1+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1,2,3)
df[grp2+'_int'] = np.linspace(2,8,3)
df[grp2+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1.5,3,3)
df[grp3+'_int'] = np.linspace(0.5,9,3)
df[grp3+'_SD'] = np.linspace(1,8,3)
print(df)
ax = df.plot.bar(x='label', y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'], yerr=df[[grp1+'_SD', grp2+'_SD', grp3+'_SD']].values)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated to add T to transpose the np.array for yerr parameter.

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

#the groups can vary 
grp1 = 'a'
grp2 = 'b'
grp3 = 'c'

df['label'] = ['ID_1','ID_2','ID_3']
df[grp1+'_int'] = [5,5.5,6]
df[grp1+'_SD'] = [1,2,3]
df[grp2+'_int'] = [7,6,5]
df[grp2+'_SD'] = [2,1,1.5]
df[grp3+'_int'] = [6.5,5,5.5]
df[grp3+'_SD'] = [1.5,1.5,2]

ax = df.plot.bar(x='label', 
                y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'],
                yerr=df[['a_SD','b_SD','c_SD']].T.values)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: On this test code that works but when I do the same thing in my larger code I get 'list' object has no attribute 'values'. Any idea how that can happen? It's just a bigger dataframe.

Comment: `df[['a_SD','b_SD','c_SD']].values` gives a list no attribue values error?

Comment: When I write that outside of the plot function it's fine and doesn't give an error. Just when it's within yerr. I copied and pasted so I don't think it's a syntax/typo situation?

Comment: Just in case, this is the whole line that I have generating the real plot: ax = dfn.plot.bar(x='sum composition', y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'],yerr=[[grp1+'_SD',grp2+'_SD',grp3+'_SD']].values)   That does throw the error

Comment: You need `df[[grp1...` I think you are missing the df.

Comment: `ax = df.plot.bar(x='label', 
                y=[grp1+'_int',grp2+'_int',grp3+'_int'],
                yerr=df[[grp1+'_SD',grp2+'_SD',grp3+'_SD']].values)`

Comment: Ok, new issue - that's progress! - now I'm getting err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ] --> the column is just a list of floats

Comment: I see that error can occur when the values are actually strings not floats, but they should be treated identically to the intensity values which are clearly floats not strings since the bars are plotting.

Comment: `yerr=df[[grp1+'_SD',grp2+'_SD',grp3+'_SD']].to_numpy(float)`

Comment: Still the same error. Tried a few different ways to force it to be a float and it still has the err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ] error

Comment: Hrm...  Can you generate data in that will reproduce this error?   This current data in this question doesn't for me.  Does it for you?

Comment: oooook. This took a surprising turn. I was trying to dig into what was different about my code than the testcode above that also does not throw an error for me. My real program was looping and subsetting a dataframe to make different bar graphs for different 'label's. It turns out that this error *only* arises for dataframes where the len(df) is < # of groups. So if there is only 1 or 2 rows in the dataframe after subsetting, but there are still 3 columns for that 1 or 2 rows, I get that error. Can fix with some logical statements, but seems weird without errorbars this plots fine.

Comment: Okay, create a small test set of data that duplicates the subsetting with error.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to revise my original question to include the test code showing when it breaks!

Comment: Okay, think, your errors data needs to be transposed.  `yerr=df[[grp1+'_SD', grp2+'_SD', grp3+'_SD']].T.values`  Double check the chart with your data to make sure this make sense.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is perfect. Seems non-intuitive to me that only some of the data would need to be transposed!! Can you update your answer to add that in case there's someone else out there who needs this?